# Installing Graphviz 2.36. on macOS Sierra

Tags: graphviz, protege

I am trying to install GraphViz plugIn on Protege. I install Graphviz2.36 package first but it doesn't work. Then I used `brew install graphviz` I got this error `Warning: graphviz-2.38.0_1 already installed, it's just not linked`. Therefore, I used `brew link graphviz` but I got this error

> Error: Could not symlink bin/acyclic
>   Target /usr/local/bin/acyclic
>   already exists. You may want to remove it:
>   rm '/usr/local/bin/acyclic'

because of this, I used `brew link --overwrite graphviz` which I got this error:

> Error: Could not symlink include/graphviz/arith.h
>   /usr/local/include/graphviz is not writable.

Anyone knows how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this by setting the following permissions

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/include/graphviz
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/share/graphviz
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/lib/graphviz
brew link --overwrite graphviz
```